# the zeros of a mean-value vanshing function

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $F:[0,1]\times M\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, where $M$ is a smooth manifold, if we have $\int_{M}F(t,x)d\mu=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, where $\mu$ est a volume form on $M$, alors does there exist $x\in M$ so that $F(t,x)=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the circle $S^1 = \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ et $F(t,x) = \sin(2\pi(x+t)).$ Then the desired integral property holds, but for any given $x$ we have $t \mapsto F(x,t)$ a sinusoid.

Comment: Good example. But is there any counterexample with the condition $\pi_1(M)=\pi_2(M)=0$?